# Finding a consistent Estimator for $\mathbb{E}(X^2)$

Tags: probability, statistics, variance, parameter-estimation

Given $X_1,\dots,X_n\stackrel{iid}{f}(x;\mu,\sigma^2)$ with population mean $\mu$ and population standard deviation $\sigma$. I want to find a consistent estimator for $\mathbb{E}(X^2)$.

By the variance formula we know $\mathbb{E}(X^2)=\mathrm{Var}(X_i)+[\mathbb{E}(X_i)]^2=\sigma^2+\mu^2$

So if I am not mistaken $\sigma^2+\mu^2$ is our estimand and we want to find an estimator that will converge to this estimand as $n\rightarrow\infty$. $\color{red}{\text{correct me if im wrong!}}$

We know $\bar{X}\stackrel{p}{\longrightarrow}\mu$ , I am assuming squaring will preserve continuity so $\bar{X}^2\stackrel{p}{\longrightarrow}\mu^2$.  $\color{red}{\text{correct me if im wrong!}}$

But I do not know how to proceed from here. It does not feel right to say $\mathbb{E}(\bar{X}^2)\stackrel{p}{\longrightarrow}\mu^2+\sigma^2$. I am assuming I will have to show it converges using chebyshev's.

I know in general $\mathbb{E}(\bar{X}^2)=\frac{\sigma^2}{n}+\mu^2$, so I was considering $n\bar{X}$   $\color{red}{\text{ (is this a good idea?)}}$

Any help or guidance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to estimate $\mathbb{E}[X^2]$, a natural estimator would be to simply take the sample mean of $X_i^2$. Then by the weak law of large numbers, $\frac{1}{n} \sum^n_{i=1} X_i^2 \stackrel{p}{\rightarrow} \mathbb{E}[X^2]$.

---

If you want to use your approach (which seems to also work when pushed a bit), a useful tool would be the [continuous mapping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_mapping_theorem). Thus we know $\overline{X} \stackrel{p}{\rightarrow} 
\mu$, and so since squaring is continuous, indeed $\overline{X}^2 \stackrel{p}{\rightarrow} \mu^2$. For the variance, we can use the usual sample variance estimator, i.e. $\frac{1}{n} \sum^n_{i=1} (X_i - \overline{X})^2$, which converges to $\sigma^2$ in probability. Then the sum of these two estimators will also converge to $\mu^2 + \sigma^2$ in probability (again, by the continuous mapping theorem).

Comment: Wow! I always forget about the property of the sum of two estimators. This concept is unusual for me because it involves bringing in formulas rather than deriving them from scratch- but this is definitely what I was looking for!